# Input box not centered on desktop

Tags: css

The input box is centered on mobile, however  desktop it does not have it centered.  [image]

What am I doing wrong within CSS with having the input box centered with the rest of the page (weight/shipping rate button)?

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.label-before, .field input:focus + label::before, .field input:valid + label::before {
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 6px;
  left: 9px;
}


.field {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top:10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.field label::before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
  transition: 300ms all;
}
.field input {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  padding-top:12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.field input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border-color: blue;
}
.field input:valid + label::before {
  content: attr(data-title);
}
.field input:focus + label::before {
  color: blue;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="my-ajax-filter-search">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="control-group">
           <div>
              <label id="label-lg">Weight</label>
           </div>
           <div class="field">
              <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" value="" >
              <label for="search" title="Pounds" data-title="Pounds"></label>
           </div>
        </div>
            
         <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="See shipping rates" />
      </form>
        <ul ></ul>
      <section class="elementor-section elementor-inner-section elementor-element elementor-element-784a76e1 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="784a76e1" data-element_type="section">
         <div id="ajax_filter_search_results" class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-no np-wrap">
 
         </div>
       </section>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the html?

Comment: @DCR   HTML added

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @WaisKamal I have removed the clutter so that it's more readable.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the **whole** of this code is causing the problem. Try limiting your code to the part that is actually causing the problem. This makes it easier for us to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.control-group{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @CorneliusWilson You're welcome. You might need to apply the same style to your form as well.